# Move up on folder from absolute path

Tags: php, directory, move

How do I accomplish to move up one folder from absolute path?

**File structure:**

```
/folder/
/folder/config.php
/folder/classes/test.php
```

From test.php I want to include_once or require_once the config.php -file.

I've tried this in test.php, but it doesn't work:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config.php');
```

Error message:
*PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/loooong-path/classes/../test.php'*

Comment: Hi, "It doesn't work" is never a good error description. Can you add some detail - what happens and what error do you get? Also, you seem to be trying to include `test.php` from within `test.php` which does't make sense?

Comment: Of course, sorry for that. Have updated my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try:

```
require_once(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../config.php'));
```

Not tested but in theory it is supposed to work.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Somebody who have a clue why not the usual way of including/require_once worked?

Comment: It behaves the same as the 2 above here but you should mention it works from 5.3.x but if it's available to your I would prefer this approach.

Comment: I had some issues with that yesterday and it was, because the path was not in my includePath.

@KeesSchepers the number of servers running version lower than 5.2 is minimal that is why I assumed that the PHP version is 5.e.x and didn't mention it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks for answers running the following PHP-version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
require_once('../config.php');
```

Comment: Get the following error message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' Im used to do like you describe, but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the reason Not found or Permissions denied?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../config.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

`require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../config.php');`